# Why cannot I add legend through ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to add legend inside the plotting area with the following R code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, size = 1, se = FALSE, color = "black") + 
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1, se = FALSE, color = "blue") +
    theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(0.85,0.85), legend.title=element_blank()) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue"), labels=c("linear","quadratic"))
```

[image]

However, I'm baffled why the legend does not show up as intended. Could someone help?

Comment: You haven't mapped anything to an aesthetic like `colour` or `fill`, so there is nothing for the legend to show.

Comment: You've told `ggplot()` **where** to make a legend, but you haven't told it **what** information you want in the legend

Comment: `stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x , size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "linear")) + 
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "quadratic"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x , size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "black")) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1, se = FALSE, aes(color = "blue"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue"), labels=c("linear","quadratic"))+
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,1), legend.position=c(0.85,0.85), legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]